# x-for does not react on data change with alpinejs and IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, alpine.js

I am building a web application which must support IE11. For dynamic content i want to use AlpineJS in its ie11 version.

But it ignores data change of my init function. The function itself is async, but even in opera and the version 2 of alpinejs it does not work.

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="m-3" id="datapanel" x-data="{
                title: window.DdsWord.getSearchParam('title'),
                results: [],
                init: async function (){
                    console.log('init called!');
                    window.results = [];
                    await window.DdsWord.initialize().then(function(data){
                        console.log(data.data);
                        results = data.data;
                    });
                    console.log('init finished!');
                }
            }" x-init="init()">
    <h1 x-text="title"></h1>
    <template x-for="result in results">
        <div>
            <template x-if="result.isHtmlContent">
                <button x-text="result.displayValue" x-on:click="window.DdsWord.addHtml(result.htmlContent);">

                </button>
            </template>
            <template x-if="result.isPlainTextContent">
                <button x-text="result.displayValue" x-on:click="window.DdsWord.addPlainText(result.plainText);">

                </button>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

The title is changing, but only on first load, if i change its later the value is never applied. Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: How you you change `title`?

Comment: @Dauros it is set on default, if you look in the data definition (x-data)

Comment: I know. You said that "if i change its later the value is never applied". How do you change `title` later? You are not changing it in your example.

Comment: @Dauros Yeah this is because I want it to work, so I changed it to the current version, where the title is directly set on definition. My main problem is that the iteration for results is not applied.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but it failed, it shows an error message like this: `SCRIPT1009: Expected '}'`. Did you find any error messages in the developer tools console? If possible,, please provide a minimal code example that reproduces the problem, and the version of alpine.js used.

Comment: I tried it with the latest Allpine.js v2 without any luck. It seems that the included `<template>` polyfill is not working.